# Check constraint fire only on Insert and not on updates PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, unique-constraint, check-constraints, integrity

My Check constraint is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT check_duplicate_rows 
CHECK (reject_duplicate_rows(columnB, columnC, columnD) < 2);
```

I want the constraint to be evaluated only when you insert a record.

Currently it does for both the insert and update statements, The problem is that my system needs to update the inserted rows and the check constraint blocks the updates.

The reject_duplicate_rows function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reject_duplicate_rows(columnB integer, columnC integer, columnD integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    results INTEGER := 1;
    v_count INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
    IF columnC <> 23 THEN
       RETURN results;
    END IF;

    SELECT total INTO v_count FROM 
        (SELECT  columnB,
                 columnC,
                 columnD,
                 count(*) AS  total 
        FROM     table_name
        WHERE B = columnB AND C = columnC AND D = columnD
        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3)
        as temp_table;

    IF COALESCE(v_count, 0) = 0 THEN
        RETURN results;
    END IF; 

    IF v_count >= 1 THEN
        results := 2;
    END IF;
    RETURN results;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN results;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION reject_duplicate_rows(integer, integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create an `UPDATE` trigger? see [Creating postgresql trigger](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/)